# Using driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-success") Not working (Python)

Tags: html, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

### Hello I have been trying to do this one thing for days what I can't do is use the class name I've got on this element when I do driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-success") But... I get this in the console

```
<https://pastebin.com/JDejrGaA>
```

Btw The thing i am clicking is a copy button if that makes a diffrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method named find_element_by_class in web driver. Please use the method `find_element_by_class_name` also this method takes only one class name at a time. You are passing three class name. Please use any one of the unique class name. 
For eg. Here the class names are btn, btn-success and alt-credentials-copy.
Please try with following code

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-success")
```

Comment: Can you give me the code please like already done cause i have no clue im new to python sorry here is the class name btn btn-success alt-credentials-copy

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check and let me know.

Comment: now im getting this error btw the thing i click is a copy button if that effects anything and thx for all the help https://pastebin.com/JDejrGaA

Comment: or basicly anyway i can click the button this is the html<button type="button" data-clipboard-text="Beachgirl119-dTi8@AltDispenser.net:vW176deelk" class="btn btn-success alt-credentials-copy">Copy</button>

Comment: I've done it mate but thx for all the help wouldn't of done it without u! here is the solution for anyone else driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn-success").click()